# PostGIS raw query returns empty set on ST_AsMVT

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to generate dynamic mvt tiles using django. I used the sql query given in the documentation to generate the tiles. I changed the z,x,y as per my requirements.

```
WITH mvtgeom AS
(
  SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(feat_polygon.geom, ST_TileEnvelope(19, 369963, 215620)) AS geom, u_id
  FROM feat_polygon
  WHERE ST_Intersects(feat_polygon.geom, ST_TileEnvelope(19, 369963, 215620))
)
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*)
FROM mvtgeom;
```

This gives empty result. But if i only run the following query it returns the results:

```
  SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(feat_polygon.geom, ST_TileEnvelope(19, 369963, 215620)) AS geom, u_id
  FROM feat_polygon
```

And if i try to run the following query it again returns the empty set.

```
WITH mvtgeom AS
(
  SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(feat_polygon.geom, ST_TileEnvelope(19, 369963, 215620)) AS geom, u_id
  FROM feat_polygon
)
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*)
FROM mvtgeom;
```

Comment: What exactly is the output of your queries? `ST_AsMVTGeom` returns a *protobuf* encoded Vector Tile in `BYTEA`. Note that `ST_AsMVTGeom` assumes your input geometries to be **projected in EPSG:3857** and if that is not the case, `ST_AsMVTGeom` will return a scaled geometry that does not fit into the envelope when passed to `ST_AsMVT`. Likewise, `ST_TileEnvelope` will return a *Polygon* in EPSG:3857, so `ST_Intersects` will only work if your initial geometries are projected as well. Try with `ST_Transform(feat_polygon.geom, 3857)` everywhere in your query.

Comment: it shows empty list. My geom are in 4326 . So, i used ST_Transform and it started returning the memory location which i think worked. But how to return it as response as it shows 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 0: invalid start byte @geozelot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ST_AsMVTGeom` assumes the input geometries to be projected in EPSG:3857; while it will happily return a scaled geometry for any coordinates within the (default or custom) bounds, they will not fit into the `ST_TileEnvelope` passed to `ST_AsMVT`.

Likewise, `ST_TileEnvelope` returns a *Polygon* projected in EPSG:3857; running an `ST_Intersects` check against geometries with any other CRS reference will fail.

Instead, wrap your geometries in `ST_Transform`:

```
WITH mvtgeom AS
(
  SELECT u_id,
         ST_AsMVTGeom(
           ST_Transform(feat_polygon.geom, 3857),
           ST_TileEnvelope(19, 369963, 215620)
         ) AS geom
  FROM   feat_polygon
  WHERE  ST_Intersects(
           ST_Transform(feat_polygon.geom, 3857),
           ST_TileEnvelope(19, 369963, 215620)
         )
)
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*,  feature_id_name => 'u_id')
FROM   mvtgeom
;
```

---

Note that you may want to either create a functional index on the projected geometries, i.e.

```
CREATE INDEX ON feat_polygon USING GIST ((ST_Transform(geom, 3857));
```

or reproject and `REINDEX` the table, i.e.

```
ALTER TABLE feat_polygon
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 3857)
    USING ST_Transform(geom, 3857)
;
```

to utilize the index in your filter.

Pedantic note: you may also want to move the main CTE into a subquery, while outsourcing the `ST_TileEnvelope` into a CTE and `JOIN` with `feat_polygon` to avoid multiple calls.

---

`ST_AsMVT` returns a `BYTEA` value that holds a [*protobuf (pbf)*](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf) encoded [*Vector Tile*](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec): you should be able to serialize a binary *protobuf* response body using

```
content_type="application/octet-stream"
```

and pass it to whatever mapping framework that can decode the *pbf* according to the *Vector Tile* specs.

Comment: Thanks, it woked like a charm

Comment: @ArshDoda glad it works! Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue. Also, you may want to join the [GIS.SE] for GIS-centric topics.